# BookAddress using localStorage (adding users)

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a contact list in which I will be saving the contacts, but when I save one or more contact and refresh the page it doesn't save. I tried to put it in the local storage but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this?

HTML:

```
    <br><br>
    Name: <input id = "name" name = "name" type = "text">
    <br><br>
    Gender: <input name = "gender" type = "radio" value = "Male"> Male
    <input name = "gender" type = "radio" value = "Female"> Female
    <br><br>
    Age: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id = "age" name = "age" type = "text">
    <br><br>
    Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id = "number" name = "number" type = "text">
    <br><br>
    Contact Type: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select id = "Contact_Type" name = "Contact_Type">
    <option>none</option>
    <option>Friend</option>
    <option>Business</option>
    <option>Educational</option>
</select>
    <br><br>
    Address:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id = "Address" name = "Address" type = "text">
    <br><br>
    Post Code:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id = "Post_Code" name = "Post_Code" type = "text">
    <br><br>
    Marital Status: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select id = "Marital_Status" name = "Marital_Status">
    <option>none</option>
    <option>Single</option>
    <option>in relationship</option>
    <option>Engaged</option>
    <option>Married</option>
</select>
    <br><br>
    <input  type = "button" value = " Reset " onclick = "ResetForm()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input  type = "button" value = " Add " onclick = "AddData(), saveList()">
    <input type = "button" value = "Remove contact" onclick = "Remove()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</form>
```

JS:

```
function AddData() {
 var x = document.getElementById("age").value;
var y = document.getElementById("name").value;
var letters = '/^[a-zA-Z]+$/';
if ((parseInt(x) != (x)) && (y == parseInt(y))) {
    alert("Wrong Value Entered");
} else {
    var rows = "";
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var gender = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked');
    gender = gender ? gender.value : '';
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
    var Contact_Type = document.getElementById("Contact_Type").value;
    var Address = document.getElementById("Address").value;
    var Post_Code = document.getElementById("Post_Code").value;
    var Marital_Status = document.getElementById("Marital_Status").value;

    rows += "<td>" + name + "</td><td>" + gender + "</td><td>" + age + "</td><td>" + number +"</td><td>" + Contact_Type + "</td><td>"+ Address + "</td><td>" + Post_Code+ "</td><td>" +   Marital_Status +" </td>";
    var tbody = document.querySelector("#list tbody");
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.innerHTML = rows;
    tbody.appendChild(tr)
    saveList();
}
}
var saveList = function () {
"use strict";
var appts = JSON.stringify(contact);
if (appts !== "") {
    localStorage.contact = appts;
} else {
    window.alert("Could not save appointments at this time");
}
};
function ResetForm() {
document.getElementById("contact").reset();
}
```

Comment: are you loading the page from a server.

Comment: Where are you defining the contact var that you are stringifying and saving to localStorage?

Comment: no it's all locally, doesn't need to be connected to the internet

Comment: yes i am storing to local storage

Comment: @Muthar i meant local server `localhost`

Comment: @Ramanlfc I am using HTML5 local storage. I am entering text into a local HTML5 webpage and trying to save it by using javascript.
An example is "localStorage.contact = appts;"

Comment: local storage is http based ,so you need to load the page from a server

Comment: The way my friend suggested to do was something like this: var storedContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage["contacts"]);

Comment: I will not be needing to connect to the internet

Comment: It's not necessary Internet. You can read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several errors.

1. HTML table is not found.
2. You're invoking `saveList` function two times (in button event and at the end of `AddData` function).
3. You aren't passing the contact parameter to the `saveList` function.
4. You should read Clean Code Book for improve your coding =).

The code should be the next (you could check the key "contact" in your browser).

HTML:

```
  <br>
    <br> Name:
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
    <br>
    <br> Gender:
    <input name="gender" type="radio" value="Male"> Male
    <input name="gender" type="radio" value="Female"> Female
    <br>
    <br> Age: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input id="age" name="age" type="text">
    <br>
    <br> Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input id="number" name="number" type="text">
    <br>
    <br> Contact Type: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select id="Contact_Type" name="Contact_Type">
        <option>none</option>
        <option>Friend</option>
        <option>Business</option>
        <option>Educational</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br> Address:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input id="Address" name="Address" type="text">
    <br>
    <br> Post Code:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input id="Post_Code" name="Post_Code" type="text">
    <br>
    <br> Marital Status: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select id="Marital_Status" name="Marital_Status">
        <option>none</option>
        <option>Single</option>
        <option>in relationship</option>
        <option>Engaged</option>
        <option>Married</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>

    <table id="list">
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value=" Reset " onclick="ResetForm()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value=" Add " onclick="AddData()">
    <input type="button" value="Remove contact" onclick="Remove()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

JS:

```
<script>
    function AddData() {
        var x = document.getElementById("age").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var letters = '/^[a-zA-Z]+$/';
        if ((parseInt(x) != (x)) && (y == parseInt(y))) {
            alert("Wrong Value Entered");
        } else {
            var rows = "";
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var gender = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked');
            gender = gender ? gender.value : '';
            var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
            var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
            var Contact_Type = document.getElementById("Contact_Type").value;
            var Address = document.getElementById("Address").value;
            var Post_Code = document.getElementById("Post_Code").value;
            var Marital_Status = document.getElementById("Marital_Status").value;

            rows += "<td>" + name + "</td><td>" + gender + "</td><td>" + age + "</td><td>" + number + "</td><td>" + Contact_Type + "</td><td>" + Address + "</td><td>" + Post_Code + "</td><td>" + Marital_Status + " </td>";
            var tbody = document.querySelector("#list tbody");
            var tr = document.createElement("tr");
            tr.innerHTML = rows;
            tbody.appendChild(tr)
            contact = {name:name, gender:gender, age:age, number:number, type:Contact_Type, address: Address, zip: Post_Code, marital: Marital_Status};
            saveList(contact);
        }
    }
    var saveList = function(contact) {
        "use strict";
        var appts = JSON.stringify(contact);
        if (appts !== "") {
            localStorage.contact = appts;
        } else {
            window.alert("Could not save appointments at this time");
        }
    };

    function ResetForm() {
        document.getElementById("contact").reset();
    }
</script>
```

Now you should program the function to read the localStorage.